# apt-offline to add custom .deb files to apt update list

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I have `.deb` files that were manually generated.

With `apt-offline install` I can synchronize them with apt cache. However if I try `apt install <package-name>` it doesn't find the synchronized deb file.

I think this is because the `apt update` feature needs to be performed to know about a package name.

Is there a way to add a `<package_name>_<version>.deb` file to the apt-update list so I can perform a `apt install <package_name>` and I don't need to specify the path of the deb file ?

*For context matters, this is performed using ansible playbook.*

Comment: You need to be at the folder where the deb file is and use `sudo apt install ./<package-name>` or give it the full path.

Comment: Yes that what I cannot do, because I use Ansible. I want that I can do `apt install <package>` and it works because `<package>_<version>.deb` has been synchronize with the cache of apt.